# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY" LINE 6:

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-2.1

I am getting error while making migrate on django 2.1 application

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('sawy', '0005_auto_20190418_0607'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='response',
            name='action',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='response', to='sawy.Action'),
        ),
    ]
```

Error:

```
 Applying sawy.0006_auto_20190418_0608...Traceback 
....
....
....

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY" LINE 6:
```

- Python Version : 3.6
- django Version : 2.1.4
- DB: Postgres

**Edit**

Modal

```
class Response(models.Model):
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='response')
    text = models.TextField(blank=True,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: Can you share your whole stack trace and also your models, please?!

Comment: have you renamed any field ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Django 2.1 have dropped support for postgres 9.3

try to update your postgres version

django 2.1 release [note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#dropped-support-for-postgresql-9-3)